# Vector bundle as an extension of line bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

This is a question about vector bundles on a smooth non-proper (non-projective) algebraic surface $X$ over $\mathbb{C}$. Are there any known examples of a non-proper surface $X$ and a rank two vector bundle $V$ on $X$ which is not an extension of line bundles, i.e. does not fit into a short exact sequence  $0 \to L \to V \to M \to 0$ where $L$ and $M$ are line bundles on $X$?

Notice that the usual topological idea of using the second Chern class does not work here.  I am asking about obstructions to restricting the structure group to the upper triangular subgroup of $GL_{2}(\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: I have in mind the case $X=Tot_{\mathbb{P}^{1}}(\mathcal{O}(-2))$.

Comment: I do not see why the second Chern class idea cannot still work.  For instance, if your non-proper surface is the complement of a closed point in an Abelian surface, then the Chow group of 0-cycles is enormous.  It seems to me that it will contain elements which are not "pure" cup products.  Using Serre's construction, presumably you can use that to construct a locally free sheaf of rank 2 whose second Chern class is not a "pure" cup product.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking of the Chern class as living in $H^{4}(X,\mathbb{C})=0$ but you are saying to consider its more natural target in $CH_{0}(X)$.  Great idea, maybe it will work for my case.

Comment: Or not because $A^{2}(X)=\mathbb{Z}$ in my case.

Comment: For the total space of a rank 1 vector bundle over $\mathbb{P}^1$, I believe a locally free sheaf of rank 2 will be an extension, as you suggest.  Consider the pullback of the restriction to the zero section.  This is certainly an extension, by Grothendieck's splitting lemma.  Also this locally free sheaf has isomorphic determinant to the original locally free sheaf; fix one such isomorphism.  Consider the torsor of automorphisms between these two locally free sheaves which induce the given automorphism on the determinant, and which restrict to the identity on the zero section ...

Comment: ... On each of the two basic open affine spaces $\mathbb{A}^2$, this torsor is trivial.  And the difference of two trivializations on the overlap, $\mathbb{A}^1\times \mathbf{G}_m$, is a morphism into $SL_2$ which is constant on the zero section $\{0\}\times \mathbf{G}_m$.  I feel like it should be possible to prove this "cocycle" is a "coboundary" by hand.

Comment: Thanks, will try.  The map you described is an isomorphism on K-theory (relative version of Quillen-Suslin) but stable isomorphism does not imply isomorphism.  The pullback of the restriction is a sum of line bundles but not every vector bundle on the space is a sum of line bundles.  Every vector bundle is known to be an extension when restricted to a formal neighborhood of the zero section.  So there are non-split bundles.  This structure can be extended to an open neighborhood of the zero section by some kind of approximation theorem  But its unclear to me if it can be extended globally.

Comment: So there is have a map $0 \to L \to V$ which some zeros away from the zero section.

Comment: (can assume the zeros are isolated)


Comment: First make an elementary transform of the vector bundle along a fiber F of projection to make the restriction to the zero section Z Cartier divisor trivial.  If you can prove the transformed bundle is globally trivial, thus a pullback under projection, then also the inverse elementary transform is a pullback, i.e., the original bundle is a 
pullback.  Now use the fact that the invertible ideal sheaf $I_Z$ of the zero section (and its powers) have vanishing cohomology (because the bundle is Tot of $\mathcal{O}(-2)$) to lift the trivializing global sections from $Z$ to the total space.

Comment: Yeah, its interesting to investigate this transform, but the original bundle need not be a pullback:  I know already that there are bundles on X which are not sums of line bundles.  If you restrict a bundle on $X$ to the formal neighborhood of the zero section $Z=\mathbb{P}^{1}$ then it is an extension of line bundles but need not be a sum of line bundles.  On the other hand, all pullbacks are sums of line bundles.  But maybe one can use these elementary transforms to simplify bundles on $X$.  My feeling was that one could lift an isomorphism only to a formal neighborhood of $Z$, 

Comment: and then using approximation to an isomorphism on an open neighborhood of $Z$.  Then when one tried to extend it to all of $X$ it might just extend as a map of sheaves but not as an isomorphism.  I am just writing this as a first impression, I will need to think more carefully!  Thanks!

Comment: Actually, altering the bundle to make it trivial on the zero section is a great thing because Murthy proved that all bundles on the singular affine surface which is given by contracting the zero section $\mathbb{P}^1$, are sums of line bundles.

Comment: @Oren -- You are right, I was wrong.  The lifts of the generating global sections will only generate on an open neighborhood of the zero section.  

Comment: Jason, about what you wrote earlier.  If the elementary transform of a vector bundle is an extension if and only if the original bundle was an extension then one could do elementary transformations and dualizations until the bundle was trivial along $Z$ and using a result of Murthy make a conclusion about the original bundle.  Unfortunately I do not understand the precise relation between an extension structure on a bundle and one on some elementary transformation of the bundle. 

Answer (score 3):

Only a partial answer, starting with the disclaimer that it does not apply when the base is the total space of a vector bundle on a projective curve. 
''If $X$ is a Stein manifold of dimension $2$, then each holomorphic vector bundle $V \to X$ of rank $r >1$ has a trivial one-dimensional subbundle''. In particular, it fits into a short exact sequence.

Proof: $X$ contains a $2$-dimensional CW-complex $K \subset X$ as a deformation retract. A generic (smooth) section of $V$ has a zero set of real dimension $4-2r < 2$, and moreover the zero set does not meet $K$ for dimensional reasons and by transversality. So $V|_K$ has a trivial complex line bundle as subbundle.

By homotopy invariance of vector bundles, this shows that $V$ has a trivial smooth subbundle. Now study the holomorphic fibre bundle $Mon(\mathbb{C};V)\to X$ (a point over $x $ is a complex linear monomorphism $\mathbb{C} \to V_x$). The fibre is the complex homogeneous space $Mon(\mathbb{C};\mathbb{C}^r)$, which is the quotient of $GL_r (\mathbb{C})$ by the stabilizer subgroup $G$ of the action of $GL_r (\mathbb{C})$ on $\mathbb{C}^{r} \setminus 0$.

The first paragraph says that there is a global smooth section $X \to Mon(\mathbb{C};V)$. Finding a holomorphic subbundle is the same as finding a holomorphic section.

Grauerts theorem (''Analytische Faserungen \"uber holomorph-vollst\"andigen R\"aumen'') says that for bundles of the above type over Stein manifolds, each smooth section is homotopic to a holomorphic section.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what surface you have in mind, but it will depend on the surface. For example, if $X=\mathrm{Spec}\,A$ is affine and Pic is trivial, but $A^2(X)\neq 0$, then you can always represent a non-zero class in $A^2(X)$ by a zero cycle defined by an ideal $I$ which is a local complete intersection. By Serre construction, one has an exact sequence, $0\to A\to P\to I\to 0$, where $P$ is a rank 2 vector bundle and its second Chern class is non-zero by construction. If $P$ was filtered by line bundles, since Pic is trivial, the vector bundle is trivial and thus second Chern class must be zero. Such examples are easy, by taking a general hypersurface of large degree in affine three space. (Technically, take a general one in projective three space of large degree and remove a hyperplane section).